# Sumar valor de una tabla relacionada consigo misma

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Hola tengo una duda sobre como realizar una consulta en sql para sumar el tiempo total que cuesta producir el producto.

El diagrama es una tabla de productos que tiene a su vez sub-productos, el diseño es una relacion N-N consigo misma por lo que hice una tabla auxiliar para almacenar lo que seria el id del producto padre con el id del producto hijo.
esa relacion la guardo en la tabla productos_x_productos con la cantidad de productos hijo en la relacion.

Estas serian las tablas

```
productos(PK idproducto, tiempo_produccion INT)                
productos_x_productos(PK idproducto_padre (FK productos.idproducto), PK idproducto_hijo (FK productos.idproducto), cantidad INT)
```

Un producto tiene un tiempo que tarda en ser fabricado, este producto a su vez puede estar compuesto por varios productos que tambien tienen su tiempo de fabricacion y ademas de la cantidad de cada sub-productos del mismo tipo.

Me gustaría saber como realizar la consulta que sume el total de tiempo para fabricar el producto lo que seria tiempo_total=tiempo_total+(tiempo_total_hijo)*cantidad (eso por cada sub-producto que tenga)

No se si se podra hacer en una sola consulta, seria lo mejor, pero si no se puede si alguien me podria orientar sobre como hacerlo en un SP.
El motor de bases de datos es MYSQL.

Comment: La consulta intente hacerla de la siguiente manera, la cual funciona y me da el tiempo total de la suma de cada uno de los subproductos y en php luego le sumo el tiempo del producto padre, pero esta consulta no esta teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de cada subproducto...       SELECT sum(tiempo_produccion) as tiempo_total
         FROM productos
         WHERE idproducto in (select productos_idproducto_hijo
              from productos_x_productos
              where productos_idproducto_padre = $idproducto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(pp.cantidad_productos * p.tiempo_produccion)
FROM productos_x_productos pp
JOIN productos p ON
p.idproducto = pp.productos_idproducto_hijo
WHERE pp.productos_idproducto_padre = $idproducto) +
(SELECT tiempo_produccion
FROM productos
WHERE idproducto = $idproducto) AS tiempo_total
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

¿Cómo lo haría yo?
De la siguiente forma...

Sabemos que el tiempo total de producción de un producto es:

```
SELECT tiempo_produccion FROM productos WHERE idProducto = "Id";
```

El último Id sería el valor que tu introducirías a la consulta.

Ahora el tiempo total del hijo sería:

```
SELECT SUM(tiempo_producción) AS tiempo_hijo FROM productos_x_productos WHERE idproducto_padre = "Id";

SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS Cantidad FROM productos_x_productos WHERE idproducto_padre = "Id";
```

Recuerda que los Id entrecomillados es donde debes de poner el Id del producto que quieras calcular.

Lo que quedaría es realizar la operación aritmética de los resultados que hemos obtenido en las consultas.

Comment: hola y gracias por tu ayuda, el problema es que el tiempo_produccion es ta en la tabla productos y no en productos_x_productos, tendria que ser algo que recorra la tabla productos_x_productos donde el idproducto_padre coincida con el del producto padre buscar el producto hijo en la tabla productos y el campo tiempo_produccion de la tabla productos multiplicarlo por el campo cantidad de la tabla productos_x_productos y sumarlo a tiempo_total, eso hacerlo por cada producto hijo, y al final de eso sumar el tiempo_produccion del producto padre. @ramón-devesa